# Power BI - How to Center Values on Clustered Column Chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there any way I can center these values?

From what I can tell, the answer is no, but just thought I'd ask in case someone knew.

[image]

Comment: What is data type for those 7 to 21? Normally they should be in center position. May be some trailing white space causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your picture, a stacked column chart would probably work great.